# Does this program only crash on x32 because of alignment differences?

Tags: c, pointers, crash, alignment, size

The following code is taken from [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-ptr):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char i = 30;
    char j = 123;
    char* p = &i;
    printf("pointer points to: %p\n", p);
    void* q = p;
    int * pp = q;   /* unsafe, legal C, not C++ */

    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    *pp = -1;   /* overwrite memory starting at &i */
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    printf("pointer points to: %p\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

On my x32 Linux machine it crashes in the last line. On x64 Linux it does not crash. Is it because pointers are 4 bytes on x32 and 8 bytes on x64 and due to alignment requirements there is probably a max 6 bytes hole between `char j` and `char *p` on x64 machine that is overwritten by `*pp = -1` and therefore nothing happens to `*p` but on x32 machine the hole is only maximum 2 bytes so that `*pp = -1` overwrites the fist two bytes of `char *p` resulting in segmentation fault when dereferencing? Is this reasoning correct or completely idiotic?

Comment: Don't forget that if you enable optimizations, `char i;` will be the only variable in memory for x64, so all the pointers can't ever get corrupted. Other things can get corrupted though...

Comment: If they're not stored memory then where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is not idiotic, but not guaranteed to be correct.

The layout of the function stack is not as fixed as you might think. While the stack pointer register is only allowed to have an address mod 4 or mod 8, depending on the alignment, the compiler is not required to follow a specific alignment. There is not even a guarantee that the data is somewhere on the stack. It might reside completely in registers!

The stack alignment you have in mind is part of the Procedure Call Standard, which says how the stack has to look like before one function calls another function and wants to transfer data via the stack. Only in that case is the compiler required to align and pad data and make sure that the address of a pointer passed as parameter resides on a 4/8 byte boundary.

In example:
Your x64 executable might run, just because the compiler keeps p in a register and not on the stack, so overwriting the stack does not affect p, even if you would memset the whole stack to zero. p would always be a valid address that can be dereferenced.

So, your code could run fine on a 32 bit machine, too or crash on a 64 bit machine. The compiler and its optimization settings will determine the result much more than the architecture.

Comment: You put me on the right track. When I compile this code with `clang` it does not fail on `x32` machine. Value of `p` is not overwritten. Does it mean that `clang` probably stores `p` in CPU register and not memory?

Comment: There is really no reasonable way to tell before what a compiler will do, if the behavior is up to the compiler. Maybe the compiler put p in a register, maybe the compiler switched the stack positions of p and q for whatever reason, maybe the compiler does align everything on 8 bytes even on x32. Only the generated assembler code can tell you the truth and this truth is only valid for this particular compiler with this particular version of the compiler with this particular flags and this particular architecture.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of compiling your code for 64 bits.

```
                .Ltext0:
                    .section    .rodata
                .LC0:
0000 706F696E       .string "pointer points to: %p\n"
     74657220 
     706F696E 
     74732074 
     6F3A2025 
                .LC1:
0017 25642025       .string "%d %d\n"
     640A00
                .LC2:
001e 25640A00       .string "%d\n"
                    .text
                    .globl  main
                main:
                .LFB0:
                    .cfi_startproc
0000 55             pushq   %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
0001 4889E5         movq    %rsp, %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
0004 4883EC20       subq    $32, %rsp
0008 C645E61E       movb    $30, -26(%rbp)
000c C645E77B       movb    $123, -25(%rbp)
0010 488D45E6       leaq    -26(%rbp), %rax
0014 488945E8       movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
0018 488B45E8       movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
001c 4889C6         movq    %rax, %rsi
001f BF000000       movl    $.LC0, %edi
     00
0024 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
0029 E8000000       call    printf
     00
002e 488B45E8       movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
0032 488945F0       movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
0036 488B45F0       movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
003a 488945F8       movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
003e 0FBE55E7       movsbl  -25(%rbp), %edx
0042 0FB645E6       movzbl  -26(%rbp), %eax
0046 0FBEC0         movsbl  %al, %eax
0049 89C6           movl    %eax, %esi
004b BF000000       movl    $.LC1, %edi
     00
0050 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
0055 E8000000       call    printf
     00
005a 488B45F8       movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
005e C700FFFF       movl    $-1, (%rax)
     FFFF
0064 0FBE55E7       movsbl  -25(%rbp), %edx
0068 0FB645E6       movzbl  -26(%rbp), %eax
006c 0FBEC0         movsbl  %al, %eax
006f 89C6           movl    %eax, %esi
0071 BF000000       movl    $.LC1, %edi
     00
0076 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
007b E8000000       call    printf
     00
0080 488B45E8       movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
0084 4889C6         movq    %rax, %rsi
0087 BF000000       movl    $.LC0, %edi
     00
008c B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
0091 E8000000       call    printf
     00
0096 488B45E8       movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
009a 0FB600         movzbl  (%rax), %eax
009d 0FBEC0         movsbl  %al, %eax
00a0 89C6           movl    %eax, %esi
00a2 BF000000       movl    $.LC2, %edi
     00
00a7 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
00ac E8000000       call    printf
     00
00b1 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
00b6 C9             leave
                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
00b7 C3             ret
                    .cfi_endproc
                .LFE0:
                .Letext0:
```

Lines 0010 and 0014 are `char* p = &i;` so you can see that variable `i` is located at memory position -26(%rbp); and only there since it is just one byte.  There we also see that variable `p` is located at memory position -24(%rbp); it extends from -24(%rbp) to -17(%rbp) because it is a pointer under 64 bits architecture.
With the code  `void* q = p; int * pp = q;` we are just loading the position of `p`; which is -24(%rbp) at variable `pp`.
So `p` and `pp` contain exactly the very same value. They are binary equal. And that value is the value of the register bp minus 26.
Lines 005a and 005e correspond to `*pp = -1;` Please note how the instruction movl is used. This is going to copy a constant of 4 bytes to the direction -26(%rbp). So the memory positions -26(%rbp) to -23(%rbp) are going to be overwritten. But remember that variable `p` was located at memory positions -24(%rbp) to -17(%rbp). **So two bytes of that variable are being overwritten!!!**
That means that `p` is no longer pointing to what it was pointing, now it points to a different memory position. One whose 2 less significative bytes are now FFFF. Pointing to memory position which is going to be larger than it was (at most 65535 more). This means pointing torwards the begining of the stack.

So it is as you suspected, two bytes are being overwritten. Even in 64 bits mode.
So the cause must be that such altered direction is out of the memory assigned to the process in 32 bits mode but not 64 bit mode. Which has more to do with the way the program is loaded into memory than with the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of this line:

```
*pp = -1;   /* overwrite memory starting at &i */
```

which leads to undefined behaviour.

On my Visual Studio 2012 I get

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'i' was
>   corrupted.

Comment: yes, I know. I said that in my question. I would like to make sure what are the actual implementation-defined reasons for which this code does not crash on x64 machines

Comment: @user1042840 your reasoning is possibly correct, but to be sure you should have a look at the generated assembly code.